# What is the precise timing and effect of SDL_UpdateRect on a double-buffered screen?

Tags: performance, sdl, double-buffering

Using a double-buffered screen with the [Simple DirectMedia Layer](http://www.libsdl.org/), is it more efficient to call [`SDL_UpdateRect`](http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/sdlupdaterect.html) once after blitting multiple images or to call it once after blitting each individual image before calling [`SDL_Flip`](http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/sdlflip.html)? In other words, will [`SDL_UpdateRect`](http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/sdlupdaterect.html) cause the screen to be updated *immediately,* or does it simply tell the Simple DirectMedia Layer which areas must be updated when the screen is flipped? How should it typically be used with a double-buffered screen?

For reference, here is the description of [`SDL_UpdateRect`](http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/sdlupdaterect.html).

> Makes sure the given area is updated on the given screen. The
>   rectangle must be confined within the screen boundaries (no clipping
>   is done).
>
> If '*x*', '*y*', '*w*' and '*h*' are all 0, `SDL_UpdateRect` will update the
>   entire screen.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `SDL_UpdateRect` update screen (or rect) immediately.

No need to use the `SDL_UpdateRect` and `SDL_Flip` jointly, they do the same things but different ways.
The difference is that `SDL_UpdateRect` can update only part of the screen (and work by copying pixels from your surface to screen), and `SDL_Flip` refresh the entire screen (and works by flip buffers).

So, if you use double-buffered screen no need to call `SDL_UpdateRect`, just call `SDL_Flip` after all blits.

http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/sdlsetvideomode.html

> Calling SDL_Flip will flip the buffers and update the screen. All
>   drawing will take place on the surface that is not displayed at the
>   moment. If double buffering could not be enabled then SDL_Flip will
>   just perform a SDL_UpdateRect on the entire screen.

And don't forget that double buffering works only with `SDL_HWSURFACE` and `SDL_FULLSCREEN` video mode.